# Check if a word exist in a url slug using php

Tags: php

My url slug is like below

```
/page-1/block-1/subpage
```

Now I want to search the slug for the word 'block'

I used stripos but it didn't give me the right output.

```
$pos2 = stripos("block", $row->uri);
if ($pos2 == true) {
    echo "We found block in '$row->uri' at position $pos2";
}
```

`$pos2` is always false here.

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pos2 = stripos($row->uri, "block");` your needle and haystack are reversed. See [official docs](http://php.net/stripos)

Comment: Just to add: if you keep getting wrong return values that aren't working, double check the PHP.net documentation.

Comment: @Jhecht - correct the first thing to do when a function doesn't work how you expect is to type `php.net/THE_NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION` in your browser and read all of the parameters, the complete return value THEN read the examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stripos($row->uri,'block')) {
echo "We found block in '$row->uri' at position ".stripos($row->uri,'block');}
```

Just to make it as short as possible, and in the right order (haystack and needle).

Answer (score 1):

You have your haystack and needle in the wrong order. The thing you are searching through goes first.

```
<?php

  $pos2 = stripos('/page-1/block-1/subpage', "block");
  if ($pos2) {
    echo "We found block in '/page-1/block-1/subpage' at position $pos2";
}
```